# JSON-LD SiteNavigationElement : itemListElement property was not recognized by the schema for subpages

Tags: warnings, schema.org, json-ld

I have a question, I am trying to make a JSON-LD code for my webpage using the "SiteNavigationElement" type scheme.

However when I try to validate it. It gets rejected with 5 warnings.
This is curious to me. Because as soon as I have a one level JSON-LD code without sub-pages it validates fine.

But when I add sub-pages it generates a warning.

Translated from Polish the validator says :

> The itemListElement property was not recognized by the schema (e.g.
> schema.org) as part of a SiteNavigationElement object.

[image]

And I have no idea how to solve this.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
    "name": "Top Level Navigation",
    "mainEntity": [
        [
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 1,
                "name": "home",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 2,
                "name": "A very nice page",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 3,
                "name": "diensten",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/all-services"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 4,
                "name": "contact",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/contact",
                "@context": "https://schema.org",
                "itemListElement": [
                    {
                        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                        "position": 1,
                        "name": "Den Haag",
                        "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                        "url": "https://example.com/contact/den-haag"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                        "position": 2,
                        "name": "Haarlem",
                        "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                        "url": "https://example.com/contact/haarlem"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 5,
                "name": "over ons",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/about-us",
                "@context": "https://schema.org",
                "itemListElement": [
                    {
                        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                        "position": 1,
                        "name": "A very nice page",
                        "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                        "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                        "position": 2,
                        "name": "Where we are good at",
                        "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                        "url": "https://example.com/about-us/we-are-good-at"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "name": "Who are we and what we are good at",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "@context": "https://schema.org",
                "itemListElement": [
                    {
                        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                        "position": 1,
                        "name": "Alle diensten",
                        "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                        "url": "https://example.com/who-are-we/all-services"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 6,
                "name": "A very simple explanation about everthing",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/a-simple-explanation"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 7,
                "name": "Nikola",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/nikola"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 8,
                "name": "Contact",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/testcontact"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 9,
                "name": "Our projects",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/our-projects"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 10,
                "name": "sddsds",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/this-works-great"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 11,
                "name": "Building your house",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/building-your-house"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 12,
                "name": "By bike",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/bike"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
</script>
```

It basically gives me a warning as soon as I start a sub-element.
But I wonder what I am doing wrong there?

```
    {
        "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
        "position": 4,
        "name": "contact",
        "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
        "url": "https://example.com/contact",
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 1,
                "name": "Den Haag",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/contact/den-haag"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 2,
                "name": "Haarlem",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/contact/haarlem"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I did start the position a new. I set the context again. But again... Without children / sub-pages it works great.

**Working example without subpages and no warnings**

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
    "name": "Top Level Navigation",
    "mainEntity": [
        [
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 1,
                "name": "home",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 2,
                "name": "A very nice page",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 3,
                "name": "diensten",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/all-services"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 4,
                "name": "A test page x 0",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/test-page-x-0"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 5,
                "name": "A test page x",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/test-page-x"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 6,
                "name": "A very simple explanation about everthing",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/a-simple-explanation"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 7,
                "name": "Nikola",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/nikola"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 8,
                "name": "Contact",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/testcontact"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 9,
                "name": "Our projects",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/our-projects"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 10,
                "name": "sddsds",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/this-works-great"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 11,
                "name": "Building your house",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/building-your-house"
            },
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "position": 12,
                "name": "By bike",
                "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
                "url": "https://example.com/bike"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, your markup uses `SiteNavigationElement` entity, which doesn't have `itemListElement` property, as defined in the Schema.org (it can be used with [`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList)).

It seems you're trying to construct multiple `SiteNavigationElement` entities in a child-parent relation.

There are a few ways to do it.

You could replace `itemListElement` property with [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart), which would then express child-parent relation, and pass the validation.

```
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "position": 4,
            "name": "contact",
            "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
            "url": "https://example.com/contact",
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "hasPart": [
                {
                    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                    "position": 1,
```

full code that passes validation:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
    "name": "Top Level Navigation",
    "mainEntity": [
      [{
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "home",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 2,
          "name": "A very nice page",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 3,
          "name": "diensten",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/all-services"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 4,
          "name": "contact",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/contact",
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "hasPart": [{
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 1,
              "name": "Den Haag",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/contact/den-haag"
            },
            {
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 2,
              "name": "Haarlem",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/contact/haarlem"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 5,
          "name": "over ons",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/about-us",
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "hasPart": [{
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 1,
              "name": "A very nice page",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
            },
            {
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 2,
              "name": "Where we are good at",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/about-us/we-are-good-at"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "name": "Who are we and what we are good at",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "hasPart": [{
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "Alle diensten",
            "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
            "url": "https://example.com/who-are-we/all-services"
          }]
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 6,
          "name": "A very simple explanation about everthing",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/a-simple-explanation"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 7,
          "name": "Nikola",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/nikola"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 8,
          "name": "Contact",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/testcontact"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 9,
          "name": "Our projects",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/our-projects"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 10,
          "name": "sddsds",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/this-works-great"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 11,
          "name": "Building your house",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/building-your-house"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 12,
          "name": "By bike",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/bike"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Also, as `itemListElement` property belongs to `ItemList` entity, you might simply add it to the `SiteNavigationElement`, which would semantically mean it's both entities, and allow you to mix properties of both entities at once:

```
            "@type": ["SiteNavigationElement", "ItemList"],
            "position": 4,
            "name": "contact",
```

full code that passes validation:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
    "name": "Top Level Navigation",
    "mainEntity": [
      [{
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "home",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 2,
          "name": "A very nice page",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 3,
          "name": "diensten",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/all-services"
        },

        {
          "@type": ["SiteNavigationElement", "ItemList"],
          "position": 4,
          "name": "contact",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/contact",
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "itemListElement": [{
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 1,
              "name": "Den Haag",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/contact/den-haag"
            },
            {
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 2,
              "name": "Haarlem",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/contact/haarlem"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "@type": ["SiteNavigationElement", "ItemList"],
          "position": 5,
          "name": "over ons",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/about-us",
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "itemListElement": [{
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 1,
              "name": "A very nice page",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/about-the-page"
            },
            {
              "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
              "position": 2,
              "name": "Where we are good at",
              "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
              "url": "https://example.com/about-us/we-are-good-at"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "@type": ["SiteNavigationElement", "ItemList"],
          "name": "Who are we and what we are good at",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "itemListElement": [{
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "Alle diensten",
            "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
            "url": "https://example.com/who-are-we/all-services"
          }]
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 6,
          "name": "A very simple explanation about everthing",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/a-simple-explanation"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 7,
          "name": "Nikola",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/nikola"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 8,
          "name": "Contact",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/testcontact"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 9,
          "name": "Our projects",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/our-projects"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 10,
          "name": "sddsds",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/this-works-great"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 11,
          "name": "Building your house",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/building-your-house"
        },
        {
          "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
          "position": 12,
          "name": "By bike",
          "description": "TEMP DESCRIPTION",
          "url": "https://example.com/bike"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
</script>
```

and it would also blur the line between the two entities, so I'd use the former approach.

Depending on what you're using structured data for, you might also consider using [BreadcrumbList](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/breadcrumb) (it seems there is no mention of child-parent relations, you just create a list of pages, and `hasPart` property cannot be used with that entity...)

Answer (score 0):

> It basically gives me a warning as soon as I start a sub-element. But
> I wonder what I am doing wrong there?

You have nested a sub-element such as the property `itemListElement` in the type `SiteNavigationElement` that does not support this property. To solve, use the properties available for the type **[SiteNavigationElement](https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement)**.